# Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, travis-ci

I have a spring boot project here: https://github.com/jcasbin/jcasbin-springboot-plugin. I encountered [the following error in Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/jcasbin/jcasbin-springboot-plugin/jobs/373086014):

```
shell
3.43s$ ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
/home/travis/build/jcasbin/jcasbin-springboot-plugin
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -Xms512m
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

It seems that the `mvnw` command fails. This file is generated by my IDE:  IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1. I don't know what it is used for and why does it fail?

I already fired an issue in Spring Boot's github issues [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13002), but Spring project said it's Maven wrapper's issue and pointed me here. I don't quite understand what it means. Is it a Maven bug? How to fix the error then?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... I believe nobody is willing to read and understand your code from zero

Comment: This isn't the error, you need to look at the maven output log for "mvn install".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're missing the `.mvn` folder in your git repository. You should have a folder called `.mvn` which contains the files `wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar`, `wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` and `jvm.config`. Perhaps you missed it because it's a hidden folder.

Try doing `git add -f .mvn` from the command line then commit and push.

Comment: Note that I actually had the .mvn directory already created and still had to do this for some reason.

Comment: In my case I had the .mvn directory but I needed to install git-lfs to be able to checkout properly maven-wrapper.jar (otherwise it is replaced by a text file)

Answer (score 122):

Phil's answer is correct.
And here is how to create .mvn directory with needed jar inside.
I found the answer here
(https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper)

If you have maven and you want to make maven wrapper working, you need to setup maven wrapper:

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

It should create .mvn directory and put needed jar in it.

Comment: Although @PhilWebb's answer maybe right, it addressed the diagnosis but not the remedy. This helped, although what is `takari` and is there a standard lib/package?

Comment: this helped us get our jhispter app working - thanks

Comment: If you're on Windows, make sure you have the `wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar`

Comment: You may check this out: 

https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper 
https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/

``` lang-powershell
mvn wrapper:wrapper
```

Answer (score 14):

## «I don't know what it is used for»:

A mvnw is a maven wrapper. Basically it is a script that decouples maven from your local installation and may add checks and features to the actual mvn command - for the complete explanation check the [official maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/index.html).

To set it up (assuming you had it running solely with `mvn`) it should suffice to run:

```
    mvn wrapper:wrapper
```

And that should create at least the following new files:

```
    .
    ├── .mvn
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── maven-wrapper.jar
    │       └── maven-wrapper.properties
    ├── mvnw
    └── mvnw.cmd
```

Then, by evoking `mvnw` you'd run everything by that maven-wrapper.jar - completely unattached from you local maven installation.

If the `maven-wrapper.jar` is not in place after the command, you probably have a network issue - the most common one is a proxy that needs to be configured.

## «How to fix»:

### What is the problem?

### Proxy issue:

Initially, the `mvn wrapper:wrapper` couldn't fetch the `maven-wrapper.jar` for me.

```
.
├── .mvn
│   └── wrapper
│       └── maven-wrapper.properties
├── mvnw
└── mvnw.cmd
```

If you take the deep dive into the rabbit hole and check the actual [wrapper code](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/tree/d89e40a2f5dc67fc75603a213b945de2a5ac0b14/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/wrapper), you'll notice there is no default proxy - but you can set a proxy for the java virtual machine by creating a `.mvn/jvm.config` file containing:

```
    -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.name
    -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
    -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.domain.name
    -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

With that in place just rerunning the setup command

```
    mvn wrapper:wrapper
```

fetched everything by itself:

```
    .
    ├─ .mvn
    │  ├── jvm.config
    │  └── wrapper
    │      ├── maven-wrapper.jar
    │      └── maven-wrapper.properties
    ├── mvnw
    └── mvnw.cmd
```

By now, running the `./mvnw clean install`, should work ok - it did for me (but only for a few days)

### Class Issue:

One nice day, I came into office and the `mvnw` was returnnig the same error you stated!...

For me the issue was actually a line ending (LF <-> CRLF) issue in the `jvm.config` file.

As the `mvnw` script expands the options into an [actual command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO4Zj.png) the command would get messed up with a CR splitting it before the classpath option. Since that classpath is where the maven-wrapper.jar (containing the MaveWrapperMain) is passed, the java command couldn't actually get the class.

**How did I fix it:**

I simply re-created the file containing only LFs and no CRLFs.

**Bonus:**

As I noticed that this CRLF was introduced by a user that was on a windows machine, I checked some [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace) to avoid repeating the issue, ran the following and advised everyone to do the same:

```
    git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

---

Hope this centralizes the steps I found scattered and ends up saving time to someone.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it got me on the path to net.properties. I was surprised that maven-wrapper seems to bootstrap before even considering proxy values in $HOME\.m2\settings.xml and I wasn't excited to place or modify a jvm.conf in each project. Maven's configure page touts jvm.conf for "options for your build on a per project base" over MAVEN_OPTS and .mavenrc file, so none of those seemed like a great fit for proxy settings. I found one reference to the JVM's net.properties. It worked and seems like the best place for proxy settings on my setup.

Answer (score 8):

1. Adding to what Oleksii Volynskyi,

use the official maven wrapper

mvn wrapper:wrapper

rather than io.takari:maven:wrapper which is no longer maintained

2. As mentioned by Phil Webb add .mvn folder to the git repository

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using Windows seeing this error, check if the `.mvn` folder files got converted to CRLF. If so, changing them to LF will likely fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had the project saved in a folder which route included a character with an accent (in my case "á"). Removing the accent fixed the problem.

Comment: That was it in my case.

Comment: Colons (`:`) are also problematic...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a `.dockerignore` file in which you select all the jar files that should be taken into account and the one in `.mvn` wasn't there, hence the error

Answer (score -2):

i actually did just mvn clean install and it worked, i am actually using older version of spring 2.0 to be specific