# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain and ClassnotFound Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I am running a basic spring application I am getting this error even though I have wrapper jar in .mvn folder. And also maven updated the project and still getting the class not found exception. I can't figure out where I am making the mistake

And also this error is shown
**Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please specify how you are starting your application? Have you checked the answers at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104172/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-maven-wrapper-mavenwrappermain)?

Comment: Yaa I am opening the spring main class and running it as java application..I am sure that the correct main class is running as a java application

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the  `.mvn` folder in your git repository. You should have a folder called .mvn which contains the files `wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar, wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` and `jvm.config.` Perhaps you missed it because it's a hidden folder.

Try doing `git add -f .mvn` from the command line then commit and push.

Comment: I am executing in the local environment only and there is no jvm.config file...I have .mvn folder with wrapper jar and wrapper properties file

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run  and this error is shown when I am running through maven commands..please help me out